# javascript count remaining value of multiple field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have 6 Field of textinput, on keypress event I want to calculate all textinput to count remaining value of div id
I already achieve this, by this code, but it really not efficient, because keypress event initialed for each div id, how I can shorten this code to make it more efficient :

```
var max_characters =  $("#maxstat").html();
            $("#str").bind("keyup", function(){
                var remaining =$("#unallo").html();
                remaining=max_characters - $("#str").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#inte").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#dex").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#con").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#men").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#sen").val();
                $("#unallo").text(remaining);                   
            });
            $("#inte").bind("keyup", function(){
                var remaining =$("#unallo").html();
                remaining=max_characters - $("#str").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#inte").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#dex").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#con").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#men").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#sen").val();
                $("#unallo").text(remaining);                   
            });
            $("#dex").bind("keyup", function(){
                var remaining =$("#unallo").html();
                remaining=max_characters - $("#str").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#inte").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#dex").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#con").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#men").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#sen").val();
                $("#unallo").text(remaining);                   
            });
            $("#con").bind("keyup", function(){
                var remaining =$("#unallo").html();
                remaining=max_characters - $("#str").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#inte").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#dex").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#con").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#men").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#sen").val();
                $("#unallo").text(remaining);                   
            });
            $("#men").bind("keyup", function(){
                var remaining =$("#unallo").html();
                remaining=max_characters - $("#str").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#inte").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#dex").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#con").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#men").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#sen").val();
                $("#unallo").text(remaining);                   
            });
            $("#sen").bind("keyup", function(){
                var remaining =$("#unallo").html();
                remaining=max_characters - $("#str").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#inte").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#dex").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#con").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#men").val();
                remaining=remaining - $("#sen").val();
                $("#unallo").text(remaining);                   
            });
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I know I stupid, but I'am not that stupid, If people asking for a question, at least give him a clue about his/her problem, not tell them to shut his/her mount
thank you for not helping

Comment: @Reids Meke Meke: I suggest you delete your comment, before you get a load of down-votes :)

Comment: @ReidsMekeMeke, I didn't tell you to shut your mouth. Way to fly off the handle. I used the tools available to me to register my vote to close this question because you want someone to review your code and tell you how to improve it.

Comment: I ask question for answer, not for reputation :)

Comment: If you're going to read what I've written there's no point in arguing with you.

Comment: If your reputation nose-dives you will not *be able* to ask questions. Best you always be polite to those that may help you here *for free* :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the code in each is identical, just combine the selectors:

```
$("#str,#inte,#dex,#con,#men,#sen").bind("keyup", function(){
            var remaining =$("#unallo").html();
            remaining=max_characters - $("#str").val();
            remaining=remaining - $("#inte").val();
            remaining=remaining - $("#dex").val();
            remaining=remaining - $("#con").val();
            remaining=remaining - $("#men").val();
            remaining=remaining - $("#sen").val();
            $("#unallo").text(remaining);                   
        });
```

Normally I would suggest putting a common class on all the elements and using that instead:

e.g.

```
  $(".myInputs").bind("keyup", function(){
            var remaining =$("#unallo").html();
            remaining=max_characters - $("#str").val();
            remaining=remaining - $("#inte").val();
            remaining=remaining - $("#dex").val();
            remaining=remaining - $("#con").val();
            remaining=remaining - $("#men").val();
            remaining=remaining - $("#sen").val();
            $("#unallo").text(remaining);                   
        });
```

Also using `on` and not `bind` is the preferred solution in later versions of jQuery.

Comment: Helo Mr Blue! Thank You! for answering and this answer is I need!
yes I'm using old jquery version 1.6.2 for some reason I didn't using the latest version jquery
Thank You Very Much!